# How to install libQt5Quick.so.5 and other QtQuick dependencies on Ubuntu?

Tags: 20.04, dependencies, qt

I'm trying to run an executable but it has some missing dependencies to QtQuick libraries:

```
ldd ./UltraNoteInfinity
./UltraNoteInfinity: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQt5Core.so.5: version `Qt_5.14' not found (required by ./UltraNoteInfinity)
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffea13aa000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff37b8c1000)
    libQt5QuickControls2.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Multimedia.so.5 => not found
    libQt5WebEngine.so.5 => not found
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ff37b8a5000)
    libQt5Quick.so.5 => not found
    libQt5Qml.so.5 => not found
```

I did

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5
```

but it did not install those missing libraries

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04

```
./UltraNoteInfinity 
./UltraNoteInfinity: error while loading shared libraries: libQt5QuickControls2.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
lz@vm:~/Downloads/UltraNoteInfin
```

I also couldn't find anything on google about this

Comment: Whereever you got that application from should explain the prerequisites, or provide the Qt libraries needed for download. It's possible it depends on a newer version of Qt than what is included in the Ubuntu repos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The https://packages.ubuntu.com provides an answer for your question - install [corresponding packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?mode=filename&suite=focal&section=all&arch=amd64&keywords=libQt5QuickControls2.so.5&searchon=contents):

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5quickcontrols2-5 libqt5multimedia5 libqt5webengine5 libqt5quick5 libqt5qml5
```

and then retry launching your application.